# How to scale multiline text by gesture in SwiftUI

Tags: text, swiftui, gesture

I need to implement multiline text scaling by gesture. I tried to use scaleEffect() but it's become blurry and pixelized (first gif). Then I tried to change font directly from gesture but faced another problem: text starts jumping, changing line breaks and etc (second gif). fixedSize() can't solve this because it's multiline text.
I need to implement scaling like with scaleEffect() but without blurring like with scaling font directly. Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var activeTextScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var lastScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var fontSize: CGFloat = 24

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack {
                Text(
                    "Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                )
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                //                    .scaleEffect(activeTextScale)
                .font(.system(size: fontSize * activeTextScale))
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.brown.opacity(0.6))
                    //                            .scaleEffect(activeTextScale)
                )
                .gesture(
                    MagnificationGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            activeTextScale = value + lastScale
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            lastScale = activeTextScale
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm tried to scale font and view accordingly, but it gives the same result as on second gif:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var activeTextScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var lastScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var fontSize: CGFloat = 24

    func getTextFontSize() -> CGFloat {
        let size = fontSize * activeTextScale
        print(activeTextScale)
        print(size.rounded())
        return size.rounded()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(
                    "Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                )
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .font(.system(size: getTextFontSize()))
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.brown.opacity(0.6))
                )

            }
            .scaleEffect(activeTextScale)
            .gesture(
                MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        activeTextScale = value + lastScale
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        lastScale = activeTextScale
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[First gif with scaleEffect()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sodr.gif)

[Second gif with font scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjvYm.gif)

[Third gif with scaling view and font accordingly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU25B.gif)

Comment: First gif : you resize size of rectangle containing text which increase the image not text font. 2nd gifs you change font size in constrained rectangle : text must cut to stay inside rectangle width. You need to change font size and rectangle size accordingly.

Comment: I edited question and added gif of how it works, but maybe I did something wrong. If I change frame directly like height * activeScaleFactor it works fine, but background starts scale too and I have dynamic text frame and don't know how to get it values.